# Divisibility of special polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Problem: classify all pairs $(k,P)$ such that $P(x)$ divides
$$x^kP(x+1)+(x-1)^kP(x-1),$$ where $k\ge4$ is an integer, and $P$ a nonconstant monic
polynomial with rational coefficients.

I have found the following four infinite families:

$k\equiv0\pmod2$: $P(x)=x-1/2$.

$k\equiv-1\pmod3$: $P(x)=x^2-x+1/3$.

$k\equiv-1\pmod4$: $P(x)=x^2-x+1/2$.

$k\equiv-1\pmod6$: $P(x)=x^2-x+1$.

And in addition a sporadic solution with $k=5$ and $P(x)$ a quartic polynomial.

Questions:

1. Are there any other solutions ?
2. Is it trivial that all such polynomials must be such that
   $P(x+1)=(-1)^dP(-x)$, with $d$ the degree of $P$.
3. Same problem with $x^kP(x+1)-(x-1)^kP(x-1)$, where I found three infinite
   families of the same type, but I did not look very hard.

Comment: Re 2: what is clear is that if $P(x)$ satisfies $P(x) \mid x^kP(x+1)+(x-1)^kP(x-1)$, then $Q(x) = (-1)^dP(1-x)$ satisfies $Q(x) \mid x^kQ(x+1)+(x-1)^kQ(x-1)$, so you have found a different solution. In the examples at hand, it happens to be the case that $Q(x) = P(x)$, but I don't see a reason why this should hold in general (i.e. why every solution is a fixed point of the involution $P(x) \mapsto (-1)^dP(1-x)$).

Comment: Over the complex numbers there are of course many more solutions. If $\bar P$ is the complex conjugate of $P$, then small degree examples suggest that in fact $P(x+1)=(-1)^d\bar P(-x)$ holds.

Comment: There are fields where $P(x+1) = (-1)^d P(-x)$ doesn't necessarily hold; e.g. in characteristic 3 with $P(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $k=6$ we get $x^k P(x+1) + (x-1)^k P(x-1) = 2 (x + 1) (x^2 + 1)^2 (x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1)$ but $P(x+1) = x^2 + 2x + 2$ and $(-1)^2 P(-x) = x^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 5):

I address the real (and sometimes complex) case. We always assume $P$ to be monic. I deal with the original condition, but that in **Q3** can be dealt with analogously.

**1.** After a substitution $Q(x)=P(x-\frac12)$, we come to a more symmetric set up
$$
  Q(x)\mid \left(x+\frac12\right)^kQ(x+1)+\left(x-\frac12\right)^kQ(x-1)=:R(x).
$$
Let $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$ be the complex roots of $Q$ counted with multiplicity.

Assume that some $\xi_i$ has a positive real part. Let $\xi$ be a root with the maximal real part. Then
$$
  \left|\left(\xi+\frac12\right)^kQ(\xi+1)\right|
  =\left|\xi+\frac12\right|^k\prod_t|\xi-\xi_t+1|
  >\left|\xi-\frac12\right|^k\prod_t|\xi-\xi_t-1|
  =\left|\left(\xi-\frac12\right)^kQ(\xi-1)\right|,,
$$
so $R(\xi)$ cannot vanish. This is impossible. The case when some root has negative real part is ruled out similarly.

Hence, $\xi_t=ix_t$ for some real numbers $x_t$. This already shows
$$
  Q(-x)=\prod_t(-x-ix_t)=(-1)^n\prod_i(x+ix_t)=(-1)^n\overline Q(x),
$$
which means $P(x+1)=(-1)^n\overline P(x)$, as suggested by @PeterMueller in the comments. In the real case, this confirms **Q2**.

**2.** Surely, the restrictions on the $x_t$ is stronger. Set
$$
  T(x)=\left(ix+\frac12\right)^k\prod_{t\neq s}(i(x-x_t)+1);
$$
then for every $x\in\mathbb R$ we have
$$
  R(ix)=T(x)+(-1)^{k+n}\overline{T(x)}.
$$
Hence we should have $T(x_s)=(-1)^{k+n+1}\overline{T(x)}$, so the real/imaginary part (depending on the parity of $k+n$) of $T(x_s)$ should vanish for all $s$. In other words, the function
$$
  f(x)=k\arctan (2x)+\sum_{t}\arctan(x-x_t) \qquad(*)
$$
should attain values in $[\frac\pi2+]\pi\mathbb Z$ at all $x=x_s$.

Notice that these conditions are also sufficient if all the $x_t$ are distinct.

**3.** Now we aim at showing that, for many pairs $(k,n)$, there exists at least one desired polynomial $Q$. This partially answers **Q1**.

*Case OE.* Assume that $k$ is odd and $n<2k$ is even; then all the $T(x_s)$ should be real. In this case, we should have $f(x_s)\in\pi\mathbb Z$.

Choose a large number $N$. Consider the set
$$
  X=\left\{(x_i,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n\colon -N\leq x_1,\leq x_2\leq\dots\leq x_n\leq N, \; x_t=-x_{n+1-t}\right\}.
$$
Now define a mapping $\phi\colon X\to\mathbb R^n$, $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (y_1,\dots,y_n)$, where $y_m<0$ ($m\leq n/2)$ is the unique solution of
$$
  f(y_m)=\left(m-\frac n2-1\right)\pi,
$$
and $y_m=-y_{n+1-m}$. (Recall that the definition of $f$ in $(*)$ depends on the $x_i$.)

Now, if $N$ is large, then $f(-N)\leq -\frac\pi2k-\frac\pi2\cdot \frac n2+\varepsilon<-\frac \pi2 n$, so that all the $y_i$ lie on $[-N,N]$. Moreover, $f$ is strictly increasing, so that $-N\leq y_1<\dots<y_n\leq N$. Hence $\phi$ is a (continuous) mapping from $X$ to itself, and it has a fixed point by Brouwer's therem.

Due to the definition of $\phi$, all the coordinates of that fixed point are distinct, so it provides a desired polynomial $Q$. According to the definition of $X$, the coefficients of $Q$ are real.

Surely, if $2k-n$ is larger than $2$, this construction allows variations.

*Case OO.* Assume that both $k$ and $n$ are odd. This case is impossible, for a real polynomial $Q$, since $Q$ should have a real root $x_s$, and at this root $T(x_s)$ is real and nonzero. However, complex polynomials can be found in the same way.

*Cases EO and EE* are similar to the case OE. In the case EO, we need to ensure that one of the roots of $Q$ is zero.

**Remark.** The cases where $n$ is much larger than $k$ look harder, as we need to ensure that $\phi$ maps $X$ to itself. Perhaps, one can redefine $X$ so that the construction would work in this case as well?